# How to connect Web Service use API RESTful Service in NativeScript?

Tags: nativescript

i'm using nativescript to build android and ios apps, i want to get data from web service. How to connect web service use API Restful in nativescript. Give me some recommend

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? Have you googled for it? Did you watch some tutorials? Where ist your code?

Comment: i watched tutorials, i had used http modules but web service had Authentication, i don't know to use it, please help me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to SO and NativeScript!

There some possible aproaches for connecting to remote web services with {N}.
Please check the NativeScript documentation for [**fetch**](https://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/fetch/HOW-TO.html) and [**http**](https://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/http/HOW-TO.html)

Also you can check a very basic example for connectiing to httpbin with  [sample-ImageUpload app](https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-ImageUpload/blob/master/app/main-page.js)

Comment: I'm having a little difficulty with authentication, i can't connect webservices